# Android Studio : Dependencies coming from github

Tags: android, github, gradle, dependencies, joystick

I'm trying to include a joystick in my app, coming from here : https://github.com/controlwear/virtual-joystick-android

Gradle settings :

```java
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```java
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tau.betterhovercraft"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'io.github.controlwear:virtualjoystick:1.10.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

And the error I get :
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hEWa.png)

I understand that it's trying to find this library but it's not searching on github and I don't know how to tell him.

I have already tried to put this line :

```java
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

and then :

```java
    implementation 'com.github.controlwear:virtualjoystick:1.10.1'
```

But I get the same error

**EDIT** :

Okay so I'm very dumb, sorry for the inconvenience, you just have to put this inside **settings**.gradle :

```java
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the maven repositories to your allprojects section?

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Edit: According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.controlwear/virtualjoystick?repo=jcenter the library is available on jcenter()

Comment: Have you tried to download one of the versions? I think it will all fail because if I remember correctly JCenter repo was shut down on Feb 1st 2022 https://testfairy.com/blog/jcenter-and-bintray-is-shutting-down-what-to-do/

Comment: Its not shut down its just not accepting new packages. Currently they do not plan to shut it down in the near future - but yeah can't hurt to save the dependencies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'jcenter()' inside your settings.gradle

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

I hope this might solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: It works, i'm just stupid.... Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm glad that I'm able to help. 

Comment: If I remember correctly JCenter repo was shut down last year...